# UDP device - device SendTo issue

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, udp

I'm working on multiplayer game on w7.

I use UdpAnySourceMulticastChannel class from RockPaperScissor example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

The problem appears when I want to play device-to-device which simply don't even want talk to each other (Send working, SendTo not) - in fact, this occurs also on sample.

devices: LG E900 & HTC Trophy

//----
Edit (after KooKiz anserw - sorry, I should wrote it at the start): 
Specify a bit:
Both devices are connected to same router and see messages send to multicast group (game lobby working)

Sample application also aren't working (see each other - game lobby working)

both applications working device-emulator

Comment: So you're asking why a 100% copy&paste from MSDN isn't working on your devices?

Comment: almost - I'm asking why orginal project wasn't working on devices.

Comment: emulator-device working and that is in fact question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP multicast usually doesn't work over internet. It works with the emulator because they are using the local network. It should also work if you connect every device to the same wifi router.

More information: [UDP Multicast over the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068497/udp-multicast-over-the-internet)

If you want the devices to communicate outside of the local network, you'll have to put a server in-between to forward the data to each device.

Comment: Is connected like that. Devices see each other and send multicast messages (Send method) - so I have a working game lobby, but when I trying send message from one device to another with SendTo (join game) (IPEndPoint is correct) device-device won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in router - when I connected to other it works, if anyone know why exactly that works with emulator-device but not device-device can say it and consider as 'correct' anserw (I'll mark that)