# Android UDP multi-cast disabled at the kernal level?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, udp

I have an interesting problem that appears to be related to `multicast` being switched off (at the kernal) on newer andriod devices, please note This is `NOT` an issue with setting up UDP on multi adapters or LTE/WIFI, I understand that.

A lot of googling and trying loads things out have offered up a multitude of answers, e.g. [acquire multi cast locks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13223018/15410) and some git hub issues where people say `its impossible as devices have multicast disabled in the kernel`. I have also just [found this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293456/why-does-multicast-reception-not-work-on-some-android-devices)

My code works fine on:-

- Nexus 5 `Andriod 8.1 - API 27`
- Lenovo Tablet `Andriod 8.1 - API 27`

That is it can send and receive UDP packets that is not directly targeted to the IP address of the phone.

It does **NOT** receive UDP packets on:-

- Pixel 3a `Andriod 10/11 APIS 29/30`

The Xamarin forms code to replicate this is:

```
    public TestCameraPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sendClient = new UdpClient
        {
            EnableBroadcast = true,
            ExclusiveAddressUse = false,
            MulticastLoopback = true
        };
        sendClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, CameraPort));

        Lab1.Text = "Started to listen for UDP packets";
        sendClient.BeginReceive(DiscoverCallback, sendClient);
    }

    private void DiscoverCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, CameraPort);
            var data = sendClient.EndReceive(result, ref ep);

            var msg = $"Received: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)}";

            //Sniff out camera IP
            var ip = $"{data[15]}.{data[14]}.{data[13]}.{data[12]}";

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Lab1.Text = $"CAMERA IP: {ip}   FULL MESSAGE: {msg}";
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            sendClient.BeginReceive(DiscoverCallback, sendClient);
        }
    }

    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = PollMessageToCamera();
        sendClient.Send(data, data.Length, "255.255.255.255", ListeningPort);
    }
```

So my questions are two fold

1. Is it possible to receive UDP packets that are **NOT** broadcasted directly to the device on a newer Andriod phone?
2. If it is possible what do I need to do to fix it?

Example output on nexus and tablets
[image: screen shot showing expected output]

I should also point out I have a console app that can send UDP messages and if I use this (ip address of pixel 3a), it works

```
sendClient.Send(data, data.Length, "192.168.1.248", CameraPort);
```

If I use 255.255.255.255 (multi cast) in console app only the nexus and tablet works the pixel 3a doesn't

```
sendClient.Send(data, data.Length, "255.255.255.255", CameraPort);
```

Comment: I don't think multicast *works* on the Internet. Do you have a special agreement with the cellphone network company?

Comment: ?? sorry what is this to do with a local wifi adapter?

Comment: Your other question said you were trying to use multicast on the internet?

Comment: @user253751 sorry you got my confused, I have only asked this question

Comment: Oh sorry, that wasn't your question. Well the answer to the other question says some devices don't have multicast enabled and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: To all that might be interested, there was no fix in the end ,so we got the camera manufacturers to provide a config change so the camera directs the broadcast (if you can now call it a broadcast) back to the orignating device that sent the orginal message.