# UDP multicast over the internet with an Android receiver?

Tags: android, udp, multicast, pim

I'm essentially trying to take a stream of UDP packets created on my local network, and get an android phone to receive them whether on that network, or cellular data as if it was on the source's local network.

I don't have tons of network experience so bear with me.. I have spent the last week researching this problem and found bits and pieces of ideas to make it happen, but I have no idea how to implement any of it.

It seems a sort of multicast with PIM sparse mode seems to be the best option. If I can have the packets routed to the rendezvous point and the phones subscribe I should be set. Looked at VPN a bit too, however Android apis would make it an annoyance to the user.

So I guess my questions in a nutshell for anyone will to put me on the right path would be:
1:How do I route local UDP packets to a rendezvous point? A special router and a port forward?
2:How can I make Android subscribe to a rendezvous point
3:Lastly, when the phone is subscribed does it act as if those packets are from its local network? Or is there more required?

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is not a good solution for your problem.  Multicast packets do not usually get past routers.  [This post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068497/udp-multicast-over-the-internet) explains why multicasting is not a good choice.

Instead write your own client/server application using standard sockets (not multicast) where the server streams the data to each client individually.